# Vmware workstation 9 wont allow ubuntu installation configuration

Tags: server, vmware-workstation

Host machine OS: Ubuntu desktop 14.04 LTS

I'm installing ubuntu-server 14.04 on vmware workstation, using recommended settings, install was successful but vmware won't allow me to choose the configuration I want. It won't allow me to choose keyboard input, location, partition, etc. Like it has automated everything for me.

Is this a bug or do I have to disable something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, this is NOT a bug.  If you tell Vmware all about what you want to install, it will do it for you.

However, if you tell vmware workstation as you create the new VM that you want to install the operating system later, this will provide the normal install. You then power cycle, booting from the ISO image and go through the steps.

Comment: To the OP of the question: This is the feature of VMware's Quick Install feature, which is for Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server.  There's no configuration necessary after that, it prompts you for some information and installs with recommended settings.